# How to disable logging for Dropwizard healthcheck

Tags: java, logging, dropwizard

I've got an application I've developed in Dropwizard (0.9), and part of our internal infrastructure routinely pings the admin healthcheck REST endpoint to validate that the service is up. This adds a great deal of:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2016:21:47:04 +0000] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "curl/7.43.0" 27
```

to the logfiles. Adjusting our internal tools is out of scope, so I'd like to configure the logger to silence these entries. Unfortunately, I can't identify the class generating these messages. Which class is responsible for the built-in /healthcheck endpoint, and will a simple:

```
logging:
    loggers:
        "com.class.that.is.responsible": ERROR
```

entry in the yaml config suppress them?

Comment: Looks like a standard logging from an HTTP service. Which one do you use?

Comment: You could do this via filters as well. Though i think DW does not necessarily make it easy to add filters to it

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the healthcheck requests with a [logging filter](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/core.html#logging-filters).

That means there's a filter class:

```
    @JsonTypeName("healthcheck-filter-factory")
public class HealthCheckLogFilter implements FilterFactory<IAccessEvent> {
    @Override
    public Filter<IAccessEvent> build() {
        return new Filter<IAccessEvent>() {
            @Override
            public FilterReply decide(IAccessEvent event) {
                if (event.getRequestURI().equals("/") || event.getRequestURI().equals("/healthcheck")) {
                    return FilterReply.DENY;
                } else {
                    return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then you register the filter class by writing its package name and class name into `META-INF/services/io.dropwizard.logging.filter.FilterFactory` file:

```
com.my.package.path.goes.here.HealthCheckLogFilter
```

And finally you add it to the configuration .yaml file:

```yaml
requestLog:
  appenders:
    - type: console
      filterFactories:
        - type: healthcheck-filter-factory
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using DropWizard [v2.0.0](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/about/release-notes.html#v2-0-0-dec-10-2019) or later, you can use the built-in `UriFilterFactory`. You can omit logs for specific endpoints by adding this to your dropwizard configuration .yaml:

```yaml
server:
  requestLog:
    appenders:
      - type: console
        filterFactories:
          - type: uri
            uris:
              - "/healthcheck"
```

Note: the DropWizard documentation uses `type: URI`, which will not work. The `@JsonTypeName` in the [source code](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/5c96cb5bdf3dbbac5ad79799ed48078009a92ebf/dropwizard-request-logging/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/request/logging/filter/UriFilterFactory.java#L18) is `uri`, so you have to use the lowercase name.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress it by adding this to your YAML config:

```yaml
server:
  requestLog:
    appenders: []
```

Those log entries are from `request log`, more information here:

https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/configuration.html#request-log

Comment: Wouldn't this suppress ALL resource logs, not just /healthcheck?